# Relating uses for integration

Tags: integration

I'm simultaneously taking introductory physics and calculus courses, and this has been bugging me for a while. In physics, I'm sometimes asked to integrate something like $ \int r^2 dm $, to find a rotational inertia for example, and find a value for dm, as a small element of a mass.

I'm capable of *doing* that, and getting the right answer, but I can't really conceptualize it properly -- in calculus, the extent of the definition for an integral I'm given is "area under the curve." What's the curve that I'm finding the area under? Why is integration used there? Is it like the idea of a Riemann sum?

I'm asking this here because I feel that this is more about the conceptual idea of integration and its applications than the actual physics.

Comment: In your $\int r^2 dm$, it is the area under the curve $r^2$ with respect to the variable $m$. You multiply $r^2$ by the small change of $m$, which gives you the small rectangular area. Adding them together, you get approximately the area under the curve. Yes, it is like Riemann sum.

Comment: So conceptually, what am I doing when I find dm in terms of dr and rewrite it? There's something similar involved in u-substitution, where you switch out one "respect" variable with another, which I have the same conceptual issue with.

Comment: That is the change of $r$ with respect to the change of $m$. For example, $\int 2m dm$, if we substitute $x=2m$, then $dx=2 dm$. That means, increasing $m$ by $1$ causes increase of $x$ by $2$.

Comment: I see -- that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!